# mongoose doesn't throw errors when an invalid data is passed to a schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following code :

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
     type : String,
     required : true
  },
  password: String,
  username : String,
});

const User = mongoose.model('User',userSchema)


const loadCollection = async() => {
   await mongoose.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser : true})
   return mongoose.connection.collection("users");
}
```

now when a user visits an endpoint i need to create a new user and for that i am using the following code :

```js
router.post('/adduser',async (req,res)=>{
    const db = await loadCollection()
    const newUser = new User({
        password : 10,
        username : 10,
    })
    try {
        await db.insertOne(newUser)
        res.status(201).send()
    } catch(e) {
        // should be triggered because of the invalid data input 
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})
```

as you can see i am passing numbers into all these values that should be of type `String` ... also im not passing the `email` which is a required field... the doc is getting saved into the database without throwing any error... note that i don't wanna use the `save()` method because i have got sub Schemas that need to be updated with `findOneAndUpdate`
is there any way to throw errors without using the `save()` method and of course using mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `validate` method.

So in your code I would probably do it as follows:

```
router.post('/adduser',async (req,res)=>{
    const db = await loadCollection()
try {
    const newUser = new User({
        password : 10,
        username : 10,
    })
       await newUser.validate()

        await db.insertOne(newUser)
        res.status(201).send()
    } catch(e) {
        // should be triggered because of the invalid data input 
        res.status(400).send()
    }
})
```

This is the [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#validating) reference